# This unanswered question isn't so unanswered

Tags: bug, status-norepro, unanswered-questions

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14123/in-an-all-out-nuclear-war-how-long-should-people-remain-sheltered) has an odd [history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/14123/revisions):

- Asked on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175396/in-an-all-out-nuclear-war-how-long-should-remain-sheltered?noredirect=1)
- *Copied* by another user into a new, separate question on Worldbuilding (which was subsequently answered)
- Migrated to [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14123/in-an-all-out-nuclear-war-how-long-should-people-remain-sheltered)
- Closed as [a duplicate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/how-long-after-nuclear-apocalypse-is-it-safe-to-go-out) of the copied version
- Content dispute notice added
- Locked
- Unlocked
- Content dispute notice removed
- Re-opened
- Merged with the question it had originally been marked as a duplicate of, which was marked as a duplicate with *this* one prior to the merge.

I tip my hat to Michael Kjörling for all the work he did on this, but there's still one problem: Despite a good, *very* well-received [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14123/in-an-all-out-nuclear-war-how-long-should-people-remain-sheltered/14126#14126) from [Mark](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/278/mark), the question still shows up on the "Unanswered" tab.

Here's a screenshot from earlier:

[image]

---

**Update**

I can no longer see the bug, so it seems to have resolved itself, but I'd be interested in seeing if anyone else has had the same issue.

Comment: You missed one step. (Hardly surprising, given the question's convoluted history.) Fixed that for you.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks.

Comment: Since this isn't happening anymore, marking as non reproducible. This was probably due to caching.

Comment: ... [shouldiblamecaching.com](http://shouldiblamecaching.com)