# Unanswered questions that are already answered

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[This question some time ago](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/this-unanswered-question-isnt-so-unanswered) flagged something that now seems to happen a lot. When I go to the "unanswered" tab, I spot 6 questions that have answers. That doesn't seem right. And some of those answers have been up for quite some time: [A Reef Without Coral](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36994/a-reef-without-the-coral) was answered on Feb. 28!

Is this a bug? A feature?

Comment: I did not know that [tag:status-bydesign] tag... is that a standard SE thing?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Yes. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unanswered means that it does not have any answer with > 0 score. So questions can be answered, but those are not upvoted.

Comment: Oh. That explains it then.